# Can an optimal weighted average ever have negative weights?

Tags: estimation, covariance, intuition, weighted-mean

I've got a few measurements $\vec{x}$ for some real-world value $\hat{x}$. These measurements have some uncertainty, and are correlated. Given these estimates, and their covariances, I want to take some kind of weighted average of the estimates

$$\bar{x} = \sum_i w_i x_i = \vec{w} \cdot \vec{x}$$

Naturally, I want my weights to sum up to 1:

$$\sum_i w_i = 1 = \vec{w} \cdot \vec{1}$$

I want to choose my weights such that my uncertainty around this estimate is as low as possible, so I want to minimize:

$$\mathbb{E} \left[ \left( \bar{x} - \hat{x} \right)^2 \right] = \sum_i \sum_j w_i w_j C_{i,j} = \vec{w}^T C \vec{w}$$

where $C$ is the covariance matrix of the errors of my measurements: $C_{i,j}=\mathbb{E} \left[ x_i - \hat{x}, x_j - \hat{x} \right]$.
Minimizing this under the constraint that the weights sum up to 1 can be done using a Lagrange multiplier, and (assuming I did everything right) results in:

$$ C \cdot \vec{w^*} = \vec{1}$$
$$ \vec{w} = \vec{w^*} / \sum \vec{w^*} $$

Note that the latter step is just rescaling $\vec{w^*}$ to sum up to 1, so I'm mostly interested in the solution of $\vec{w^*}$:

$$ \vec{w^*} = C^{-1} \cdot \vec{1}$$

This procedure results in negative weights. This doesn't make sense for me intuitively. (E.g. if I have just one estimate $x_1$ of 100, then obviously my total estimate $\bar{x}$ will also be 100. How could the introduction of another measurement, of 110, make it so my overall estimate $\bar{x}$ *lowers* to below 100?) So I suspect that I'm doing something wrong, like using an inconsistent covariance matrix. But is it *definite* that I am doing something wrong?

Can the above procedure *reasonably* return negative weights? How would this make sense in terms of the actual implications of what I'm trying to do (take a weighted average of multiple estimates)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to the other excellent answer.  Yes, it can give negative weights, in some cases, even if that can look counterintuitive. Let us see. First, I will go through solving the minimization problem (and I will simplify your notation, replacing $\vec{w}$ with $w$ and so on).

Introducing the Lagrange multiplier $\lambda$, define
$$ L(w)= w^T C w -2 \lambda (w^T 1-1). $$ Then we find the partial derivatives 
$$ \frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda}= w^T 1 - 1 \\ \frac{\partial L}{\partial w} = 2 C w - 2 \lambda 1 $$ Setting this equal to zero, and solving assuming $C$ is positive definite (so invertible) we find
$$w = \lambda C^{-1} 1. $$To find $\lambda$ start with $w^T = \lambda 1^T C^{-1}$ and postmultiply with vector $1$ gives $\lambda=\frac1{1^T C^{-1} 1}$ so finally
$$ w = \frac{C^{-1}1}{1^T C^{-1} 1}. $$ If $C$ is only positive-semidefinite (so inverse do not exist) then the variance is minimized (and equal to zero) by any $w$ in the nullspace of $C$. Let us look at this in the case of two measurements of the same real-world quantity $X$. If the covariance matrix (of measurement errors) have nullspace with dimension 1, this means that the two error terms are linearly dependent, a highly impractical case. But then we have the model
$$
  y_1 = X+\epsilon \\ y_2=X+c\epsilon $$ for some error variable $\epsilon$ with expectation zero and variance $\sigma^2$. This means that with probability 1 the error term $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2$ belongs to the linear subspace $\{ (x_1, x_2)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \colon x_2=c x_1\}$. The orthogonal complement of this space (which is the nullspace of $C$) is $\{(w_1, w_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2 \colon w_2=-w_1/c\}$, and this subspace then contains optimal weights$^\dagger$.  Then we can calculate that 
$$
   (y_1, y_2)^T w = (X+\epsilon) w_1 + (X+c\epsilon)w_2 = X(w_1+w_2)+(\epsilon w_1 + c \epsilon w_2) =X(w_1+w_2)+\epsilon(w_1-c w_1/c) = X$$
when we in the last step has used that $w_1+w_2=1$. So the negative weights in this case makes it possible to filter the error term *completely*, to leave an estimate without error!

But negative weight do not occur only in this unnatural case. By a continuity argument, if the correlation is sufficiently close to 1, we could expect something similar to occur even if $C$ has complete range, so is positive definite. Continuing the above case with $n=2$, write $C$ in general form as 
$$
  C=\begin{pmatrix} \sigma_1^2 & \rho \sigma_1 \sigma_2 \\ \rho\sigma_1\sigma_2 & \sigma_2^2\end{pmatrix}
$$ 
Then we can find the inverse as 
$$
 C^{-1}=\frac1{(1-\rho^2)\sigma_1\sigma_2}\begin{pmatrix} \frac{\sigma_2}{\sigma_1} & -\rho \\ -\rho & \frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_2}\end{pmatrix}
$$
and then we can find the weights are proportional to 
$$
(w_1,w_2) \propto \frac1{(1-\rho^2) \sigma_1 \sigma_2} \left(\frac{\sigma_2}{\sigma_1}-\rho, -\rho+\frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_2}\right)
$$
Now, if $\sigma_1=\sigma_2$, the weights are equal and positive, but when these are different, for some correlations sufficiently close to 1, one of the weights is negative. For instance, if $\sigma_1 < \sigma_2$, then we get $w_2<0$. So the weight of the least precise measurement is negative.  **The intuitive explanation is that for correlation $\rho$ sufficiently close to 1, both error terms will with high probability have the same sign, so it makes sense that one of the weights should be negative**.

$^\dagger$ Note that in this argument we have really assumed that $c>0$ (and if $c=1$ the argument will need modification). If $c<0$ much the same will be true, but we must replace "correlation close to 1" with "correlation close to $-1$".

Comment: (+1) Nice answer that explores the $n=2$ case more completely (and makes it explicit that you don't need a rank deficient covariance matrix for negative weights).

Answer (score 4):

In abstract theory, yes, because of the correlation structure.

If you had uncorrelated measurements (with positive variance), then the weights could only be positive.

#### Example:

Let $\mu$ denote the true value. Let noisy measurement $X_1 \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, 1)$. Let $X_2 = 2X_1 - \mu$, hence $\operatorname{E}[X_2] = \mu$ but $X_2$ is perfectly correlated with $X_1$. The covariance matrix is $ C = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 4 \end{bmatrix} $.

The solution is $\mathbf{w} = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} $. Observe $2X_1 - X_2 = \mu$ and that linear combination has no variance (because $\mathbf{w}$ lies in the null space of $C$).

(As @kjetil b halvorsen points out and explores more deeply in his answer, negative weights aren't limited to degenerate cases like this.)

#### An equivalent finance problem:

An almost equivalent problem is solving for the [minimum variance portfolio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_portfolio_theory) in finance.

Let $R$ denote a vector of $n$ returns. Let $C = \operatorname{Cov}(R)$ denote the covariance matrix of $R$. Let $\mathbf{w}$ denote a vector of portfolio weights.

The minimum variance portfolio is found by solving:

\begin{equation}
 \begin{array}{*2{>{\displaystyle}r}}
 \mbox{minimize (over $w_i$)} & \mathbf{w}'\Sigma \mathbf{w} \\
 \mbox{subject to} & \mathbf{w}'\mathbf{1} = 1
 \end{array}
\end{equation}

This is exactly the same problem and it has exactly the same solution. For invertible $C$:

$$ \mathbf{w}_{mvp} = \frac{C^{-1} \mathbf{1}}{\mathbf{1}'C^{-1}\mathbf{1}}$$

Perhaps in the portfolio context, it's more intuitive that the minimum variance portfolio may involve both going long and short assets? (Note: before you run off and try to start an investment fund realize that estimating $C$ has big time problems.)

#### Some linear algebra interpretation

Let $U'\Lambda U = C$ be the eigenvalue decomposition of $C$. (This is basically [PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis)). Then $Y = R U$ is a random vector of uncorrelated random variables whose variance is given by the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues $\Lambda$. The minimum variance portfolio will give you positive weights on these random variables $Y_1, \ldots, Y_n$ but since these components are themselves linear combinations of security returns, you may get positive and negative weights in security weight space.

Comment: Maybe this is tangential to the question, but I'd be interested in learning more about the "big time problems" associated with computing $C$ -- is it as simple as past performance not being indicative of the future, or is it more subtle? This is purely for my edification (+1)

Comment: @Sycorax If you have $n$ returns, then you have $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ covariance terms. So the moment you start moving off a few huge categories (eg. S&P500 etc...), you start having an explosion of terms to estimate. The correlation structure also changes over time. Anyway, estimating covariance matrices is itself a big topic. (Estimating expected returns is even worse.) Naive portfolio optimization typically suffers from a "wacky weights" problem (eg. it tells you to go long Europe 300% and short Japan 200%). Garbage input leads to garbage output.

Comment: These are all good points! Thanks for sharing! I've been playing around with reinforcement learning for portfolio optimization purely on a lark so I have a hobby interest in the topic.